# Why do my handle bars wobble from side to side?

Tags: electric-bike, new-bicycle-assembly, steering, newbie

I am a gramma with my first electric bike.  When I ride I notice my handlebars and wheel tend to flip from side to side a lot.  Is this because I am out of practice riding or does something need readjusted?  It is a Nakto Skylark 22" ebike with no shifting gears.  I am 5'2" over 200lb.s and generally riding on uneven side walks but it also happens when I am just going straight.

Comment: Are you positive the bike was assembled correctly?   Adding a photo of your bike might help pinpoint any problems.   You can do this with the [edit] link, and then one of the buttons is "insert image".   Its not impossible for a bike-in-a-box to be assembled wrong.   +1 for getting back on a bike - that's awesome.

Comment: I can't find a 22" model - the Nakto Skylark seems to be a brand for both a 26" wheel that doesn't fold,  and a 16" wheel size that folds.   Both are electric.   Comparing with your bike might show if there's an assembly error.   Also if its the 16" folder, they are definitely more twitchy than a conventional bike, and take some time to get used to.

Comment: Going straight and level the front wheels and handlebars should not try to flop to one side, or oscillate back and forth. if you include pictures of the front end of your actual bike we may be able to spot something wrong, but as this is a safety issue you should take it to a bicycle repair shop.

Comment: grammashirl, do you mean that the handlebars and wheel move together and steer the bike (much more than you would expect) or that the handle bar and wheel move separately?

Comment: If this happens when going very slow then that is normal.

Comment: @grammashirl could you please provide some updates to the questions raised?  Use [edit] to put them into your answer or just reply in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing on my 20in viking ebike. Mine was down to the folding tensioner on the handle bar release handle.I tightened that and it sorted out the problem.  [image][image]